# Password expired in Magento when trying to add Database

Tags: php, database, magento, mysql-error-1064

I have a problem. When I try do add a Database during the Magento Installation this error message comes up. Do you know any answers to that error?

Error message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1862] Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.